# Waveguide cut off frequency derivation - Wave equation to Helmholtz equation

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, maxwell-equations, vector-fields, waveguide

I'm trying to derive the cut off frequency for a wave guide. I found a [derivation on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency), but I don't understand the first step where we go from the wave equation to the helmholtz equation. Why does only considering $\psi(x,y,z,t)=\psi(x,y,z)e^{i\omega t}$ mean you can go from the wave equation to the helmholtz equation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By guessing a time dependence of the form $e^{i\omega t}$ you remove the time dependence from the equation. specifically, it transforms to the Helmholz equation.

I recommend you set $\psi(x,y,z,t)=u(x,y,z)e^{i\omega t}$ and substitute into the wave equation and do the algebra and see for yourself.
You'll get the Helmholz equation on the spatial part  $u(x,y,z)$.

I suggest you read on [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations)

Comment: I think I see it now, let $\psi (x,y,z,t)e^{i\omega t}$ in the wave equation, then expand the brackets. I see where the $\omega^2 $ comes from now in the helmholtz equation, but where does the $-e^{i\omega t}$ go when you take the second derivative wrt t?   Oh, does it cancel out with the other $-e^{i\omega t}$ from the lapace?

Comment: sorry for the delay. the factor $e^{i\omega t}$ indeed cancels out with the one left over from applying the Laplacian . @David